# CSS float causing element to overlap

Tags: css

I am a little confused, and would appreciate some help.

I'm looking at the article on float at MDN, and I copy and paste their example and change it a little, and it comes out how I would expect it to - the floated element is to the left of the next element.

However, I then create a second test in jsfiddle, and this time the floated element is on TOP of the next element.

(Please see the snippets).

Float to the left:

```css
h4{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h4>HELLO!</h4>
<pre>
This is row 1 of some text.
</pre>
<pre>
This is row 2 of some text.
</pre>
<pre>
This is row 3 of some text.
</pre>
<pre>
This is row 4 of some text.
</pre>
```

Float on top:

```html
<div style="float: left; height: 100px; width: 100px; background: blue"></div>
<div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: orange"></div>
```

Can someone please explain to me what exactly is going on?

Comment: I tell you what. After fifteen years of coding CSS, I am actually not sure haha! It must have been a long day! Erm! I know if you also float the second then the result is as desired by OP, but a definitive answer eludes me.

Comment: You should include links to JS Fiddle

Comment: Thanks for your replies, guys, in future I will post a link to my jsfiddle instead of attaching a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a coloured background to the `pre` elements in your first example, then it should become clear: *`float` affects text wrapping, but does not fundamentally change the flow of the page or change the size of elements*.

If you added text to your orange box in example 2, you should see that it is wrapped.

**Edit**: here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tj1appLf/

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely correct there - and I added text to the orange box as you suggested, and you're right, the text is wrapped! https://jsfiddle.net/aub2v0Lk/1/

Comment: I can see that. But WHY does it not affect the flow of the page? A div is a block level element, so if you have two, both with defined width and height, and you float the first left, wouldn't you expect the second to butt up against it on the right hand side? This is a great example of not understanding the very basics, when I (think haha) I understand far more difficult concepts!

Comment: @mayersdesign: the MDN description explains this clearer than I can: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float#Specifications. In particular, "The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and *placed along the left or right side of its container*, where *text and inline elements will wrap around it*." (emphasis mine). The behaviour that you're describing can be achieved with `display: inline-block`, or by floating multiple divs as you suggested above :-)